# Topological number of 1-D p-wave superconductor---Kitaev model/wire

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, topological-phase

After learning the Kitaev model, I tried to reformulate it and encounter some conceptual loopholes of my own.

Here the setting:
Given the 1-D chain Hamiltonian (differed from original form proposed by Kitaev, here we slightly modify coefficient and the pairing terms with anticommutator $\{c^\dagger_{j+1},c^\dagger_j\}=0$ in order to get a more simple BdG Hamiltonian): 
$$
H=\sum_{j=1}^{N}\bigg[\frac{-t}{2}\big(c^\dagger_{j+1}c_j+c^\dagger_{j}c_{j+1}\big)-\mu c^\dagger_{j} c_j+\frac{\Delta_0}{4}\big(c^\dagger_{j+1} c^\dagger_j-c^\dagger_j c^\dagger_{j+1} +\text{h.c.}\big)\bigg],
$$
where $t$ is a hopping coupling, $\mu$ is the chemical potential, and $\Delta_0$ an induced pairing gap function that we by convention chose as real and positive. One can perform a lattice Fourier transform with
$$
c^\dagger_{j}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}\sum_ke^{ikR_j}c^\dagger_{k},
$$
where $R_j=aj$ and $a$ is the lattice constant set to one for simplicity. Thus,
$$
H=\sum_k\bigg[-t\cos k c^\dagger_{k}c_k-\mu c^\dagger_k c_k+\frac{\Delta_0}{4}\big(e^{ik}c^\dagger_{k}c^\dagger_{-k}-e^{-ik} c^\dagger_{k} c^\dagger_{-k}+\text{h.c.}\big) \bigg]\\
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_k \begin{pmatrix}
 c^\dagger_{k} &c_{-k}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
-t\cos k-\mu&i\Delta_0\sin k\\
-i\Delta_0\sin k &t\cos k+\mu
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
c_k\\c^\dagger_{-k}
\end{pmatrix}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_t \cos k +\mu;
$$
the above gives the energy spectrum
$$
E_\pm(k)=\pm\sqrt{\big(t\cos k +\mu\big)^2+\Delta_0^2\sin^2 k}.
$$
To see the topological features of this theory, let's rewrite the BdG Hamiltonian (matrix) into Dirac Hamiltonian $\mathsf{H}(k)=\mathbf{d} (k) \cdot \boldsymbol{\sigma}$ with
$$
\textbf{d}(k)=-\big(0,\Delta_0\sin k, t\cos k+\mu \big),
$$
 running in a $(\sigma_y,\sigma_z)$-plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is regard as the space of Hamiltonian as $k$ sweeps over the entire BZ. The trajectory of $\textbf{d}$ is an ellipse centered at $d_z=-\mu$. Together with fact that the energy spectrum of this parametric theory provides the clues for finding physically distinct phases and one can see, for $\Delta_0\neq0$, the gap closes at
$$
 t\cos k +\mu=\sin k=0,
$$
 which is valid at "$k=0$ with $\mu=-t$" and "$k=\pi$ with $\mu=t$".

**So far so good, here is the point where weirdness starts:**

Therefore, for $k$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$, there are ***three*** phases:

- For $0<t<\mu$, $\Delta>0$ the origin is outside the loop which is a trivial phase.
- For $\mu=0, t>0$ the origin is inside the loop which is topological and has winding number 1.
- For $\mu=0, t<0$ the origin is still inside the loop, but the winding number is -1.

Hmm...I get **1** trivial phase like Kitaev model, but **2** non-trivial phases corresponding to winding number $\pm 1$!

But normally (see p198 of Bernevig and Hughes's book) we say that Kitaev chain has the topological number/invariant of $\mathbb{Z}_2$, i.e. $0,1$ (mod $2$). So $w=1$ and $w=-1$ would be the same phase. That is, one can transform from one to the other without closing the gap(, which is true and I know it.)

It is known that, in general, *topological* classifications are done by finding an integer number called topological invariant. Thus, naively I would expect different topological numbers would correspond to distinct topological classes (or phases.)

**My question would be:**

Where did I do wrong? And how should I explain the topological number $w=\pm1$ I got correspond to the same phase, while the general statement is that---we can classify distinct topological phases with these topological numbers?

My main references are:
[1]Bernevig and Hughes's book.
[2]Kitaev's original paper.

*I've been searching for relevant questions and answers on SE for a while and didn't find much. If there is any worth digging, please let me know :p

Answer (score 8):

You are correct in observing that $w=+1$ and $w=-1$ are labeling the same topological phase of the Majorana chain. This paradox is resolved by understanding that the **winding number $w$ is not the correct topological index** for the Majorana chain. In this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.4938.pdf, it was shown that **different winding numbers can correspond to the same topological phase** of the Majorana chain, so there is indeed a "degeneracy" in the winding number.

There are at least two reasons why the winding number fails to serve as a topological index of the fermionic symmetry protected topological (SPT) phases:

- The winding number, as calculated from the **free fermion topological band theory**, is not expected to work once the *fermion interaction* is introduced. However the **fermionic SPT phases are in general interacting**, so one should not expect the winding number to label the SPT phases correctly.
- Even if we restrict ourselves to the free fermion SPT phases, the winding number is still not a good idea, because it is only well defined in the presence of a specific type of the **time-reversal symmetry** in the symmetry class **BDI**, where the time-reversal $\mathcal{T}$ act on the fermion as $\mathcal{T}^2=+1$. (As a side comment, we must also understand that there are many versions of Majorana chains depending on the symmetry class. For example, the BDI class has a $\mathbb{Z}_8$ classification, while the D and DIII classes have $\mathbb{Z}_2$ classifications. So it is also wrong to say that the Majorana chain has a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ topological index without specifying the symmetry class in the first place.)

The correct classification of Majorana chains is either based on the **K-theory** in the **free fermion** limit (for more discussions, see [Topological insulators: why K-theory classification rather than homotopy classification?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/104258/topological-insulators-why-k-theory-classification-rather-than-homotopy-classif)), or based on the **$\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded group cohomology theory** (see Fidkowski-Kitaev https://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.4138.pdf) or the **spin cobordism theory** (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.7329.pdf) for the **interacting** case. In any case, the winding number $w\in\mathbb{Z}$ (or the **homotopy theory**) is *never* used as a topological index to label/classify the SPT phases. Just think that we don't even have a $\mathbb{Z}$-classified Majorana chain, so how can the $\mathbb{Z}$-valued winding number possibly be correct?

But *loosely speaking*, it is still fine to think that the topological index is "related" to the winding number *modulo some integer*. For example, for the class DIII Majorana chain, the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ topological index $\nu_\text{DIII}$ is related to the winding number $w$ by $\nu_\text{DIII}=w\text{ mod }2$, such that $w=+1$ and $w=-1$ are labeling the *same* topological phase, which is uniquely identified by the correct topological index $\nu_\text{DIII}=1$ without the $\pm1$ discrepancy.

Comment: Thank you for perfectly answering my doubts and providing useful comments and references! Although there are still a lot for me to digest, it's really helpful!